# Find all references to method and references to references in Java

Tags: java, methods, reference

I have a method in my Java application and I need to get all ways this method invoked from root of the first call inside of my application. In Eclipse I can find a nearest caller to the method but I need to find also a caller to this caller and so one till the root of each call. Is there any tool which can do it or approach which can help?